# maven is not downloading spring shell starter dependency

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I just have created a spring boot starter project in IntelliJ Idea with no extra dependencies added. After that I am trying to add spring-shell-starter dependency in it.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I am syncing it, its not downloading the dependency and showing the error -
**Cannot resolve org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-starter:pom:2.0.1.RELEASE failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.shell:spring-shell-starter:pom:2.0.1.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.**

Here is the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-shell-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring-shell-demo</name>
    <description>spring-shell-demo</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Please help me out with this.

Comment: Have you tried to invelidate ItelijIdea cache? `Main Menu | File | Invalidate caches`

Comment: Go to plain console (not within your IDE) and do `mvn clean package -U`...

Comment: @khmarbaise
Its not working.

Comment: Invalidating the caches worked for me.

Comment: Are you inside a coroprate network with firewall/proxy etc. ?

Comment: @khmarbaise
No. Its my home computer.

Comment: The error message `The operation was cancelled.` looks weird...

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve the same issue,it looks like there is a mistake on the groupId declaration, try with:

```
        <groupId>org.springframework.shell</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-shell-starter</artifactId>
```

Thanks!